# Construct incenter of tetrahedron

Tags: geometry, 3d

How do I construct the incenter of a tetrahedron? Assuming that the tetrahedron in question is not regular/isoceles, of course.

Comment: What do you mean by "construct" ?

Comment: By incenter, do you mean the center of the unique sphere internally tangent to the four sides ?

Comment: compass + straightedge, and yes, the center of the insphere.

Comment: If you are interested by an analytical method, here is a short one (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.math/VsGH4BioURE).

Comment: Do you really use compass and straightedge for 3D ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you assume the tetrahedron is not isosceles?

Comment: How do you use compass in 3D?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The incenter is the intersection of the bisector planes of the dihedral angles formed by three tetrahedron faces which don't have a common vertex.

If $ABCD$ are your tetrahedron vertices, to obtain the bisector plane of planes $ABC$ and $ABD$, construct on those planes respectively lines $AC'$ and $AD'$, perpendicular to $AB$. The plane formed by the bisector of $\angle C'AD'$ with $AB$ is the bisector plane of faces $ABC$ and $ABD$. Repeat the same construction for faces $ABC$, $ACD$ and then for faces $ABC$, $DBC$.

See picture below for an example, showing perpendicular lines $AC'$ and $AD'$, their bisector (blue line) and the bisector plane of the dihedral angle formed by $ABC$ and $ABD$ (blue plane). Point $O$ is the incenter.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This question is computationally explored (not ruler&compass-explored) 
in the MathematicaSE posting, [Insphere for Irregular Tetrahedron](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33846/194),
which supplements @JeanMarie's link.

---

[image]

---